# Triggers in SQL syntax issue in code SQL DB2

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

**Question:**

My code works until it reachs **last line** then it throws a syntax error.

Error :

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was    not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "temp_dept" was found following "(case when ".
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".  SQLSTATE=42601

I am trying to do this:

- After each insert on RD_EMP
- for each row
- insert into RD_Supervisor
- check for cases, if temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 0 THEN RD_Supervisor.RD_E_SUP 0

Code:

```
create trigger RD_total_dep_emp \
after insert on RD_Emp \
referencing new table as temp_dept
for each statement \
   insert into RD_Supervisor(RD_E_SUP, RD_E_EMP, RD_QUOT) \
   select temp_dept.RD_E_ID, 
       (case \
         when temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 0 then 0 \
         when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 0 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 15 then 15 \
         when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 15 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 25 then 25 \
         when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 25 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 35 then 35 \
         when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 35 then 100 \ 
        end) as RD_E_SUP \ 
   from temp_dept
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three columns in the `insert`, but only two in the `select` -- and they appear to be in the wrong order.  The following is probably more your intention:

```
create trigger RD_total_dep_emp \
after insert on RD_Emp \
referencing new table as temp_dept
for each statement \
   insert into RD_Supervisor(RD_E_EMP, RD_E_SUP) \
       select temp_dept.RD_E_ID, 
           (case \
             when temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 0 then 0 \
             when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 0 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 15 then 15 \
             when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 15 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 25 then 25 \
             when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 25 AND temp_dept.RD_E_ID <= 35 then 35 \
             when temp_dept.RD_E_ID > 35 then 100 \ 
            end) as RD_E_SUP \ 
       from temp_dept
```

If there is a value you want to set for `RD_QUOT`, then you can specify that as well -- both in the `insert` and the `select`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem after all these headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You have an opening parenthesis before CASE, but you don't have a closing parenthesis after END.

https://xkcd.com/859/

Comment: Hi, I checked and put the extra bracket I still have an error thrown. I also edited my post and described what error.